# Cassandra db PHP driver, cannot page queries with both ORDER BY and a IN restriction on the partition key

Tags: php, cassandra, paging

I cant get results for the following query using datastax PHP driver,

```
select * from track where id='35209' and day in (20180314,20180315,20180316) and datetime < '2018-03-15 11:00:00' order by datetime desc limit 1;
```

> error message : "Cannot page queries with both ORDER BY and a IN restriction on the partition key; you must either remove the ORDER BY or the IN and sort client side, or disable paging for this query"

So how can I disable paging when "executeAsync" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable paging by passing calling `withDefaultPageSize` on `Cluster.Builder` object, and passing `null` as an argument...

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE music (artist text, album text, tr_num int, song text, PRIMARY KEY((artist), album , tr_num)) with clustering order by (album DESC ,tr_num DESC);